# setMaxFiles to upload in dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I want to set the maximum number of files reached in dropzone.js by setting the 'maxfilesreached' property as follows:

```
 maxfilesreached: function () {
      alert("Max Files reached")
  }
```

It is not firing on reaching maximum files.

How to trigger this event?

NOTE: I am using this dropzone.js in ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Simple Code to Set Maximum Numbers of File

```
<form class="File" id="my-file"></form>
```

and JS:

```
File.options.my-file = {
maxFiles: 1,
accept: function(file, done) {
console.log("uploaded");
done();
 },
init: function() {
this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file){
    alert("No more files please!");
});
 }
};
```

Comment: it is not triggering. I have used it inside <script> of my .cshtml and called.

Comment: Check Using Alert Function Whether your Function Will Call or not